# How to test __get() in Node object?

Tags: 8, testing

I've created UnitTest based class for my service.

In one of my tested methods from service class I have code like:

```
if ($node->hasField('field_foo')) {
  $section = $node->field_foo->entity;
}
```

I've created mock for Node class and I know how to "emulate" hasField. However, how to mock this line:

```
$section = $node->field_foo->entity
```

I'd to set $section to be a Term object (or mock). Is this even possible?
Now my test falls with an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

but this is clear why. I'm using just mock, not real Node object.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you please post your entire test method and the method you are trying to test?

Comment: All that I can add is that $section is returned from this method, so that's why line that I wanted to distinct is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, magic methods afaik can't be mocked.

You can use get('field_foo')->entity which does exactly the same as __get(), at least in this case. And then make that return a stdClass object with a ->entity property. That's not exactly the same as what really happens, but it will work in the same way for your code.